# Proof that $\mathcal R^\perp(A) = \mathcal N(A')$

Tags: linear-algebra

I want to show that $\mathcal R^\perp(A) = \mathcal N(A')$

I've written up the following so far but I'm not sure how to show that $\pmb {\dot y} \neq A^T \pmb x$ implies that $A^T \pmb{\dot y} = 0$.

What I have so far:

($\implies$)

The definition of $\mathcal R^\perp(A)$ is that it's not in $\mathcal R(A)$. Everything in $\mathcal R(A)$ is in the row space where the row space is everything in the span of $(c_1 \pmb a^T_1 + c_2 \pmb a^T_2 + \cdots + c_n \pmb a^T_m)^T$. This is equivalent to writing that the span includes all values of $\pmb y$  defined by $\pmb y = (\pmb x^T A)^T = A^T\pmb x$. The definition of $\mathcal N(A^T)$ is that $A^T\pmb x = 0$. If $\pmb {\dot y}$ is out of the column space then $\pmb {\dot y} \neq A^T \pmb x$ for all $\pmb x$ therefore...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align*}
u\in\mathcal{N}(A^{\intercal}) & \iff A^{\intercal}u=0\\
 & \iff\forall x\colon x^{\intercal}A^{\intercal}u=0\\
 & \iff\forall x\colon(Ax)^{\intercal}u=0\\
 & \iff u\in\mathcal{R}(A)^{\perp}
\end{align*}

Comment: Starting from the other end with if and only ifs. That's a better approach. I was trying to be too sequential